# Hot to uninstall apps on user device using flutter and know if user clicked cancel or ok

Tags: android, flutter, dart

How to work with the UNINSTALL_PACKAGE intent properly in flutter. I am trying the below code

```
    android_intent.Intent()
  ..setAction('android.intent.action.UNINSTALL_PACKAGE')
  ..setData(Uri.parse("package:${apps[0].packageName}"))
  //..putExtra('android.intent.extra.RETURN_RESULT', '1')
  ..startActivityForResult()
      .then((value) => print('s'), onError: (e) => print(e))
      .catchError((e) => print(e));
```

I get the pop up for uninstalling apps but as soon I click cancel the app crashes and i get below error.

```
: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=999, result=0, data=null} to activity {com.ameybanaye.madeinindia/com.ameybanaye.madeinindia.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Reply already submitted
```

Answer (score 0):

```
setAction(android_action.Action.ACTION_DELETE)
```